# Ignoring constant potential energy

Tags: energy, potential

The reason why constant potential energy terms are dropped is because the derivative of a constant is zero. And since force is the gradient of potential energy, constant terms won't change what the force is.

So imagine a PE vs. x-direction graph, and imagine some PE function shifted up by some constant. Consider the function to be something like $-(m_1 + m_2)gx$ + const where $x$ is the only parameter measured from a specified location where PE = 0. If I drop the constant term so that the function becomes $-(m_1 + m_2)gx$, is $x$ now measured, not from where PE was specified to be 0 before, but where the new PE = 0  is (i.e. where the constant term became 0 is the new PE = 0)?

Comment: Yes. If you use $mgh$, PE is 0 where $h$ is 0.

Comment: Your reference for the 0-point is for you to chose arbitrarily. It doesn't matter if you shift it all up or down. When ever you calculations, it is still just the difference you are using, so any shift disappears.

Comment: Funny that nobody comes up with an example. This is physics, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $x$ can be measured from any arbitrary origin.  Nature doesn't care where you set your coordinate system.  At times there are choices of origin that make the math easier, but as far as the physics goes, it makes no difference at all.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, any constant should be ignored.

Comment: That is a bit too short to constitute a good answer. Also, what do you add over the existing answer?

Comment: @Martin length is not a requirement for an answer.

Comment: @DavidZ: Not for an answer, but it is a requirement for a good answer except for very rare circumstances. That said, you are right, I should've just downvoted and not flagged.